# Ruby: How can I dynamically build a hash from user input

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like this below

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4.....z: 26}
```

now user input 1 then I will fetch first 5 if user input 2 then 6 to next 5 means 6 to 11

How can I acheieve this by a best way

Comment: You could improve your answer in a couple of ways. 1) `h` should be a valid Ruby hash (no `....`), so readers can cut-and-paste rather than having to construct the hash.  Also, `....` leaves the impression that you are lazy. 2. If you mean it to be an arbitrary hash (which I assume is the case), you should not have such a regular pattern (`:a`, `:b`, `:c`,... and `1`, `2`, `3`,...) as some readers will interpret your question as referring to that specific hash.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please define what you mean by "best way". Also, what do you mean by "like this"? Is it always that exact hash? What's the pattern that makes the hashes "like" this one?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this at all: "now user input 1 then I will fetch first 5 if user input 2 then 6 to next 5 means 6 to 11".  Could you please edit your question to show specific examples for the different inputs and corresponding outputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4.....z: 26}

user_input = 1

Hash[h.to_a[((user_input - 1) * 5 )..( (user_input * 5) - 1)]]
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4, :e=>5}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the question concerns an arbitrary hash.

**Code**

Three choices:

*#1*

```
def select_em(h, which_block_5)
  select_range = (5*which_block_5 - 4)..(5*which_block_5)
  h.select.with_index(1) { |_,i| select_range.cover?(i) }
end
```

*#2*

```
def select_em(h, which_block_5)
  select_array = Array.new(5*(which_block_5-1),false) +
                 Array.new(5,true) +
                 Array.new(h.size-5*(which_block_5),false)
  h.select { select_array.shift }
end
```

Note

```
 select_array = Array.new(5*(which_block_5-1),false) +
                Array.new(5,true) +
                Array.new(26-5*(which_block_5),false)
   #=> [false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true,
   #    false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
   #    false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

*#3*

```
def select_em(h, which_block_5)
  start = 5*which_block_5 - 4
  stop  = start + 4
  h.select.with_index(1) { |_,i| (i==start..i==stop) ? true : false }
end
```

This method uses Ruby's [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/).

All of these methods use [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) (which returns a hash), not [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) (which returns an array).

**Examples**

```
h = {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4, :e=>5, :f=>6, :g=>7, :cat=>"meow",  :dog=>"woof",
     :h=>8, :i=>9, :j=>10, :k=>11, :l=>12, :m=>13, :n=>14, :o=>15,
     :p=>16, :q=>17, :r=>18, :s=>19, :t=>20, :u=>21, :v=>22, :w=>23,
     :x=>24, :y=>25, :z=>26} 

select_em(h, 1)
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4, :e=>5} 
select_em(h, 2)
  #=> {:f=>6, :g=>7, :cat=>"meow", :dog=>"woof", :h=>8} 
select_em(h, 3)
  #=> {:i=>9, :j=>10, :k=>11, :l=>12, :m=>13} 
select_em(h, 4)
  #=> {:n=>14, :o=>15, :p=>16, :q=>17, :r=>18}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do:

```
char_ary = ('a'..'z').to_a
start_idx = (input - 1) * 5
subary = char_ary.slice(start_idx, 5)
subary.inject({}) do |h, c|
  h[c.to_sym] = char_ary.index(c) + 1
  h
end
```

This doesn't need a hash to be defined with all the alphabets.

Comment: I believe the hash given was just an example. If is was that particular hash, you wouldn't have to do any slicing or selecting, just construct the 5-element hash directly.

Answer (score -1):

So you can simply use slice array function to split out things.

```
   alphabets = [*('a'..'z')].collect.with_index{ |key,index| { key => index+1  }  } 
   user_input = 1 # Capture user input here. 
   part_of_array = alphabets[( (user_input - 1) * 5 )..( (user_input * 5) - 1)]
```

Converting into simple one hash use the below code.

```
part_of_array = eval(alphabets[( (user_input - 1) * 5 )..( (user_input * 5) - 1)].to_s.gsub("{","").gsub("}",""))
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: This code will generate array with standalone hashes: `[{"a"=>1}, {"b"=>2}, {"c"=>3}, {"d"=>4}, {"e"=>5}]`

Comment: Simple. 
eval(alphabets[( (user_input - 1) * 5 )..( (user_input * 5) - 1)].to_s.gsub("{","").gsub("}",""))

Comment: My comment on @Jagdeep's answer applies to yours as well.